# I am getting this invalid syntax error and I do not see error. Could someone help me locate the syntax error?

Tags: python, django, syntax-error

```
from django.urls import include, path

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [path('polls/', include('polls.urls')), path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

```
  File "C:\Documents\Projects\mysite\polls\urls.py", line 1
    This is line 1
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `This is line 1` is definitely not Python

Comment: Nor is it in the posted code.  The irony is that 'This is line' *is* syntactically valid, which is why the caret points to '1'.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the problem.

```
  File "C:\Documents\Projects\mysite\polls\urls.py", line 1
This is line 1
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`This is line 1` is not at all python code.